# C:\Users Folder shared by default with everyone?- Security Fault?Compromised data?

Tags: windows-7, security, passwords, network-shares

yesterday i was very confused about finding out, that my C:\Users Folder under Windows 7 are fully shared.

So i googeld out and found this TechNet article:
https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff660257(WS.10).aspx

but i dont understand what Microsoft in wrote at the Details.

So my question to you:

I use my Windows 7 many years in public Wifi#s or VPN's, can any other Person Access my private data at my user profiles? for example my documents or something like that?

My Windows 7 is an Home Premium and  no Member of an Domain or Workgroup. The first time i used my Windows user 2 years without an Password, since 3 years i have an Password.

My Knowledge says that you Need the username and the Password of an local User to Access Shares on an single Windows 7 PC, is that not right in this case?

normally, when i have an user withhout an Password the Access to Shares where blocked by Windows.

I dont changed the Permissions of my user profiles (right click on the Folder->Security-> There is only following User/Groups:

System: Fullaccess
MyUser: Fullaccess
Administrators (PCNAME\Administrators): Fullaccess

So im really scared about the safety of my personal files.

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you classify the foreign networks as public network no-one is going to be able to access your shared folders. The integrated Windows firewall protects you from rogue share access if the network classifaction is correct.

Comment: My Network is classified as an Home Network, but there is an explicit Option at the Network control Center for activate or deactive Password protected Shares...By Default Password protected is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

i found this post here at super user:

### ["Users" folder shared with everyone](https://superuser.com/questions/690318/users-folder-shared-with-everyone/690322#690322)

"There is a known phenomena that shares the entire users folder, related to public folder sharing."

### "Please note however, that share permissions stack on top of disk permissions, so if your user profile does not allow Everyone Full Control, then the share permissions don't override that. in fact MS recommends that all shares use permissions of Everyone Full Control, and that the folders shared implement actual permissions. "

Means in my case, the Share of Directory "C:\Users" has fully access, but my user profiles in C:\Users\profilename doesnt have an "anyone" permission, so my data are secured.

So any other Person can see via VPN/Public WLAN only my "Users" Share, but this share is completly empty for him.

Is that right?

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).